# Is there an ODataSerializer to serial custom objects?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf-data-services, odata, datacontractserializer

I need something to take an arbitrary Object/List/Dictionary returned to me by a call to a WCF Service to be serialized to OData. I am currently using the WCF Data Services October 2011 CTP to accomplish this, generating the ODataEntry/ODataFeed etc, using reflection, but if there is already something implemented I'd rather use that instead of reinventing the wheel...

Any help / information would be greatly appreciated.

For example:

```
Person p = new Person()
{
PersonID = 1,
FirstName = "Bob",
LastName = "Smith",
Address = new Address()
     {
          AddressID = 1,
          Address1 = "1 Main St",
          Address2 = "Suite 200",
          City = "Columbus",
          State = "OH",
          ZipCode = "43215"
     }
};
```

would translate to

```
{
  "d":{
    "__metadata":{
      "id":"Person(1)","uri":"http://serviceroot/Person(1)","type":"MyProject.Person"
    },
"PersonID":1,
"FirstName":"Bob",
"LastName":"Smith",
"Address":{
              "AddressID":1,
              "Address1":"1 Main St",
              "Address2":"Suite 200",
              "City":"Columbus",
              "State":"OH",
              "ZipCode":"43215"
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered [webapi-odata](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData) ?

Answer (score 1):

Since the OData format is [JSON](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v2-documentation/json-format/), i would suggest using [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text). It is a fast .NET serializer written exactly for such purposes. It is part of the [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) web services framework and the usage is really simple.

1) Import and reference ServiceStack framework in your project (either via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Text) or directly from [GitHub](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text))

2) Create and fill the complex object as you already do:

```
Person p = new Person()
{
    PersonId = 1,
    FirstName = "Bob",
    LastName = "Smith",
    Address = new Address()
    {
        AddressId = 1,
        Address1 = "1 Main St",
        Address2 = "Suite 200",
        City = "Columbus",
        State = "OH",
        ZipCode = "43215"
    }
};
```

3) Call the **ToJson** extension method from the complex object:

```
p.ToJson();
```

4) Voila - the output (as desired):

```
{
  "PersonId": 1,
  "FirstName": "Bob",
  "LastName": "Smith",
  "Address": 
  {
    "AddressId": 1,
    "Address1": "1 Main St",
    "Address2": "Suite 200",
    "City": "Columbus",
    "State": "OH",
    "ZipCode": "43215"
  }
}
```

Hint: In order to print the output for debug purposes use **PrintDump()**:

```
p.ToJson().PrintDump();
```